# A modified std::invoke/std::apply, taking the callable as a void* - possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, higher-order-functions, std, c++17

In C++17 we have `std::invoke` :

```
template<class F, class... ArgTypes>
std::result_of_t<F&&(ArgTypes&&...)> invoke(F&& f, ArgTypes&&... args);
```

(and in C++11 there was already `std::experimental::apply` which is similar, but with a tuple). Now, I want to implement:

```
template<typename T, typename... ArgTypes>
T invoke(void* f, ArgTypes&&... args);
```

The difference from `std::invoke` is that f is passed via a void pointer, and without a template parameter for its type. However, the type *can* be inferred by the human reader, provided that `f` is a pointer to a plain freestanding function, and I can do this:

```
template<typename T, typename... ArgTypes>
T my_invoke(void* f, ArgTypes&&... args)
{
        using type_unerased_function = T (*)(ArgTypes...);
        return reinterpret_cast<type_unerased_function>(f)(args...);
}
```

which seems to work. However, `std::invoke` supports member functions, objects with `operator()`, and maybe other critters (and `std::apply` supports more than plain function pointers also). Can the above be extended to support most/all of what `std::invoked` does?

**Notes:**

- I removed the constexpr from the signatures since I'm willing to forego that. If somehow constexpr can be preserved that would be neat.
- I may be messing up the forwarding/&&'s here.

Comment: "I removed all information about the type of my object. How can I know the type of my object?" By not removing the information in the first place, of course. I'm having a lot of trouble imagining what you might be thinking, writing this question; I'm not able to come up with any interpretation of the question that allows for a useful answer.

Comment: @hvd: Doesn't what I implement make my intention clear? The function pointer's type information is redundant, since the arguments' types are sufficient. The question is whether I can somehow make this work for more complex callables.

Comment: Sort of, but unless I'm totally misunderstanding your question, what you're asking for is not possible, since you pretty much set it up to be impossible. And that isn't a useful answer. (In general, BTW, argument types are insufficient even for function pointers. Consider calling `void f(long)` with an argument of type `int`.)

Comment: @hvd: Actually that is a useful answer, in the sense that it's what I wanted to know - if that is actually the case. But "I don't see how it can be done" and "I am certain it can't be done" are two separate answers, and just the second one is useful.

Comment: Your pointer function is not even the right one. even if argument of `my_invoke` is passed by const reference, the original function may pass by value...

Comment: @Jarod42: Can you explain that some more? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: With `void foo(std::string, const std::string&)`, `my_invoke<void>(&foo, "string"s, "string"s)` will use `void(*)(std::string, std::string)` and even worst, `my_invoke<void>(&foo, "ptr", "ptr")` will use `void(*)(const char(&)[4], const char(&)[4])`

Comment: It's generally a horrible idea to try to infer a callable's signature from the types and value categories of the arguments later passed to invoke it. Doubly so when you have no way to check whether the inferred result is correct.

Comment: @einpoklum:  The problem is that the function pointer's type information is *not* (completely) redundant.  Only the argument types and return type are redundant -- the callable type (freestanding function, member function, object, lambda) is not redundant and you've lost it.

Comment: @einpoklum You cannot trust the determined types of arguments as prototype (like what was in C). References, integer-float conversions, int-long conversions, pointers to derived classes, etc., could all mess things up.

Comment: @user1887915: I see what you're saying about references, but the rest of all that is essentially how in the typed version you could provide a function which is not exactly the same type as the arguments, but they are convertible to its accepted types, and here you would have to hope that the function is _exactly_ the right type.

Comment: @Jarod42: That would just be using the wrong-type function. Obviously without the type information I can't prevent these kinds of mistakes. In the templated invoke you get conversions, in my version you obviously don't. But it's a fair observation to make I guess.

Comment: @einpoklum But, it is too difficult to achieve a right type without mention the correct argument type, and impossible sometimes (when arguments containing rvalue reference). For a hard case, `int a = 3; const int b = 4; my_invoke<int>(f, a, b, 3)`, compiler assumes `f` has type `int(int&, const int&, int)`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd The problem is even the stuff you think are redundant are not redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Never, ever use deduced argument types to determine what a static or reinterpret cast (or C-style) argument should be.

Compatible deduced arguement types do not match what they are compatible with.

```
void f(short);
```

can be called with `0`, but `0` is deduced to be of type `int&&`, and your code casts the void pointer to `void(*)(int)`.  These are not compatible types.

What more, if you take `int zero=0;` then pass `zero` to your monstrosity, you deduce the void pointer to be `void(*)(int&)`.  While the first may accidentally work based on stack alignment (go go undefined behavior), this one will segfault immediately (which at least makes you notice your error, as opposed to missing it and getting confused later on).

The type of the arguments you expect to call a given function with *IS NOT SUFFICIENT* to determine the type of the thing you call.  And even when it is, it is fragile and dangerous and a grue will get you.

Now, you want to extend it to a pile of other stuff.  Each of those has different layouts and calling conventions.  Member function pointers can vary in size, and there is no guarantee they *fit* in a `void*`, let alone can be treated like a function.

---

Now the good news.  Your problem is that you are erasing at the wrong spot.  You need to erase *when you have the information you need*, not long after you threw it away.

You do need to know what kinds of arguments you expect to feed this erased object.

Suppose you know it will be called with types `arg1, arg2, arg3`.  Then we can store it in a:

```
std::function<void(arg1, arg2, arg3)>
```

So now you do:

```
std::function<void(arg1,arg2,arg3)> f = my_invokable;
```

and `std::function` will do `std::invoke` step of handling function pointers, objects with `()` overloaded, and member function pointers (where the first argument is now `this`).

---

Odds are this question is really an attempt to solve a scripting interface generation somesuch.  As most such questions, someone tried to solve it, said "if only I could solve this sub-problem I'd be done", then asked about the sub-problem without including motivating context.  Please reduce your questions like the above, but *always include motivating context*.

Your problem can probably be solved by type erasing at a different point than where you do.